# how to find table with particular pattern in the name

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have a set of tables with names such as `table<N>` where `N` is a non-negative integer. I need to find the table with the 'greatest' name in the lexicographical order. That is the name with the greatest `N`. `SHOW TABLES` lists all the tables, and I could not find a way to do it more efficiently than fetching the whole list in to the client and scanning it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to achieve this?

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
ORDER BY table_name DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

You can, of course, add a `WHERE` clause to this too:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name LIKE ('numberedTable%')
ORDER BY table_name DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

if applicable.